# Compare values in a table cells

Tags: html

```
Col:1 Espresso Truffle, Green Tea, Black Tea, Green Tea, White Chocolate Mocha, Black Tea   
Col:2 Caffe Espresso Cappuccino, Caffe Espresso, White Chocolate Mocha, Green Tea, Black Tea 
Col:3 Black Tea, Doubleshot Espresso, Caffe Espresso, Caffe Latte, Caffe Latte, Black Tea   
Col:4 White Chocolate Mocha, Green Tea, White Chocolate Mocha, Green Tea, Black Tea
```

I have this kind of HTML table, I want to color the table cells according to the cell value.
e.g.- if perticuler cell value appears on all 4 columns I want to color all of them by blue color

1. "Black Tea" and "Green Tea"appears in all 4 columns so all the "Black Tea"  and "Green Tea" cells will be blue
2. "White Chocolate Mocha" appears in only 3 columns so "White Chocolate Mocha" cells will be Red
3. values appears only 2 columns Yellow
4. "Espresso Truffle" only appears in one column so it is Not colored.

What is the best method/Algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1):

it's just an idea. Assuming using PHP as script language. You could fill an assoziative array with the positions of each entry.

```
$arr['Espresso Truffle']=array(array('row'->0, 'col'->0));
$arr['Green Tea']=array(array('row'->0, 'col'->1),array('row'->0, 'col'->3));
```

or shorter

```
$arr['Espresso Truffle']=array(array(0,0));
$arr['Green Tea']=array(array(0, 1),array(0,3));
```

In one side you only store the same name 1 time. And with the count() command you can easy see the amount of each entry.